# Get a Facebook page's posts from a PHP website

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm developing a friend's company web site (PHP). He would like to display last Facebook posts from his professional Facebook page.

I'm using the Facebook Graph API for the first time and the documentation is huge and not user friendly at all. Anyway I created a Facebook App. After retrieving OAuth token it looks as simple as:

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$pageId."/feed?access_token=".$token."&limit=10&fields=message,link,attachments,created_time,full_picture,picture,timeline_visibility");
```

**BUT** from what I understand this requires the `Page Public Content Access` permission. To get it you need to review your app.

The review process is insane! My app was rejected 3 times and they didn't explain how to make it pass. Each time they simply replied with this laconic message:

[image]

Is there any other way to get the posts of a public page?

Thanks a lot for your help! It will be much appreciated!

Comment: No, this does not need Page Public Content Access (and they will not grant it to you, for such a use case.) Using a page access token granted by a page admin, is the way to go here.

Comment: I'm now the page admin and it still doesn't work. I tried to get a page access token with this command `curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?fields=access_token&access_token={user-access-token}"` but got a 400 bad request error and the following message: `Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature`. What is wrong?

Comment: Did the user grant the permission `pages_read_engagement`?